# Finding repeating pairs of specific numbers within column (Matlab)

Tags: matlab, matrix

I'm stuck on this probably very trivial problem.

I have a matrix like this (just much larger):

A = [1 3 4 8 10 12 14 17 19; 5 30 90 30 50 70 5 30 5]'

I'm now looking for pairs of specific numbers in A(:, 2). For example, I'd like to find all 30s that are preceded by 5s in A(:, 2) and extract the corresponding row in A(:, 1).

So I'd like to end up, in this example, with B = [3, 17];

How can I do that in Matlab? Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run:

```
num_wanted=30;
num_previous=5;
is_match=[ false; A(1:end-1,2)==num_previous & A(2:end,2)==num_wanted ]; %the first element cannot be a match
A(is_match,1).',
```